# Break out of if statement in while loop

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement, while-loop, exit

Not sure if it's possible but I'm trying to break out of an `if` statement that's in a `while` loop. I do not want to exit the `while` loop though. I tried using `exit` and `break` but both exit the while loop.

The problem is that I don't know which folder the file I'm looking for is in, which is why I want to exit the current `if` statement when I match the searched file so that I can move on to the next serial number.

I have a text file called `drives-fw-sn.txt` that contains a list of serial numbers. Breakdown of code:

- I read in one serial number at a time from `drives-fw-sn.txt` using a `while` loop
- I search for a file called `output_log` using `find`
- I then print the first occurrence of the serial number from the found file
- Next I print that the log has been found and want

Here's a snippet of my code (there are more than three test folders). Note that it still contains the `exit` commands which exit the `while` loop.

```
while read node; do
   if find ./test1/*log* -maxdepth 2 -type f -name output_log -exec egrep -m 1 $node {} \; ; then
     echo "Log SN $node available"
     exit 1
   fi
   if find ./test2/*log* -maxdepth 2 -type f -name output_log -exec egrep -m 1 $node {} \; ; then
     echo "Log SN $node available"
     exit 1
   fi
   if find ./test3/*log* -maxdepth 2 -type f -name output_log -exec egrep -m 1 $node {} \; ; then
     echo "Log SN $node available"
     exit 1
   fi
done < drives-fw-sn.txt
```

Comment: have you tried using a case statement in bash?

Comment: @KaranShah i thought about using a case statement but i don't think it would be very suitable for my application

Comment: The exit status of `find` is unrelated to the exit status of the command executed with `-exec`, or to how many files are found by `find`. The exit status is 0 unless there is an actual error in running `find`.

Comment: At least as written; there is no "early" point to break out of the `if` statement; you only have one non-exit command in the body of each. The body of an `if` statement is all or nothing, so you generally structure your code appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually pretty simple using the `return` built-in. Inside the `while` loop, set the `if` statement inside a small function block. When the `if` condition is met during the iterations, you can have it call the `return` where the script will return to the place where the function was called and continue from that point. I will show you with an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Input: ' HEY

func() { if true; then return; fi; }

while true; do

   echo "Input received!"
   func && break

done
```

In the `func` function, you have a very basic `if` statement that can hold any conditional value you want, such as your multiple conditions. When you include the `return` keyword, the `if` statement will then send the interpreter's "program counter", if you will, back to the point where the `func` function was called. Which in this case is inside the `while` loop. So it will be as if the function was not even called and as you can see, the next command in the while loop is a `break` keyword which will end the `while` loop. The function that contains the `if-then-return` code can be inside OR outside of your `while` loop as long as the conditions you place inside the `if` statement have been loaded into the interpreter first (bash reads scripts from top to bottom, similar to how C code is loaded).

There is also a lazy method and that is to wrap the entire script code inside a main function so you can use `return` at any point in your script, no matter if it is a loop or conditional statement. Here is an example of the above script modified in this manner:

```
#!/bin/bash

MAIN() {
read -p 'Input: ' HEY

while true; do

    if [ "$HEY" == "hello" ]; then
       return
    else
       echo "Incorrect input! Try again!"
       MAIN
    fi

done
}

MAIN

echo "Correct input received!"
```

Doing it in this manner as well will help keep variables local rather than creating global variables. To do this, at any point in the `MAIN` function you can define a variable as local so it only holds the value given to it while the `MAIN` function is running. Once the function is complete, the variables and their values are no more.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to break out of the `if`, per se.  But from the looks of your example, you could  the `continue` command instead of `exit` to iterate the loop immediately.

Answer (score 0):

`continue` is the correct answer to your specific question how to "break out" of an `if` statement. Be aware that the `if` check is not actually checking if grep was successful, see the comment by chepner.

I would do this in a way that circumvents the problem in the first place:

Since you don't know which directory the file containing the serial number is going to be in, it doesn't matter in which order you're looking at them. Instead of listing all the directories separately and run `find -exec` on each of them, you can have grep just try all the log files directly:

```
while read -r node; do
    cat **/output_log | grep -m 1 "$node" && echo "Log SN $node available"
done < drives-fw-sn.txt
```

This requires the globstar shell option, `shopt -s globstar`, to enable the `**/` construct. Depending on your directory structure, you might not even need it and could use something like `test*/*log*/output_log` instead.

`cat` is used to prevent grep from checking other files once it has found a match.

The output is a little different: the matches are prepended by the filename, but that can be adjusted with the corresponding grep options (`-h` to suppress filenames).

It also looks like you don't need regular expression matching; if so, you can use `grep -F` for fixed strings, which should be faster.

Lastly, depending on what the serial numbers look like, you might want to use the `-w` option (match only complete words) to avoid false positives due to substring matches.

Comment: I didn't specify here in this question but I can't directly use grep because there are too many files in the directories and using grep this way will use up too many bandwidth. Using find first and then grep alleviates this issue.

Comment: @stevo What do you mean with "Too much bandwidth"? Does the command line get too long?

Comment: By bandwidth I meant that the search uses up too much resources on the server and grinds operations to a halt. The find and grep method is less taxing on resources

Comment: @stevo You could try adjusting the niceness: `while read -r node; do nice grep ...`, or even `nice -n 19` for the lowest possible scheduling priority.

Comment: @stevo Hmm, I realize that this goes through all other files even after a match... I'll update.

Comment: From the operating system's point of view, there is no difference between `find` launching all the `grep` processes and the shell doing the same thing.

Comment: @chepner The main point of my answer is to avoid having to list all the directories separately, which could also be done with a single `find` command, but I've since learned that the reason for multiple commands is strain on resources.

Comment: @chepner My understanding is that using find to locate the files first and then running grep is more efficient than using grep to find the files. But it's possible I am incorrect. The engineer that maintains the log server advised this method based on monitoring system resources.